# Open a file in output panel

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to open a file in output panel, but I can't find such method in API docs. For example:

```
import sublime_plugin

class OpenInOutputPanelCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        window = self.view.window()
        output = window.create_output_panel('temp')
        output.set_read_only(False)

        # output.run_command('open_file', {'file_name': 'test.txt'})
        window.open_file('test.txt')
        window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "output.temp"})
```

This opens a file in new tab, instead in named output panel.

So how is it possible to open a file in output panel with sublime API (without explicitly reading the file through Python and dumping it)?

Comment: You've answered yourself in the question - it isn't. An output panel is for the output of a build system or plugin, it's not for displaying files. The contents of any file you would want to display would need to be sent through Python first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation. I was trying to load image, that's why I asked without Python...